# Time complexity of O( n log(log n)) + n O(L)

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I want to find the overall time complexity of this:

```
O( n log(log n)) + n O(L)
```

where `n` is the number of objects and each object has a string with length `L`.

Comment: Usually if you say "I want to find the time complexity of this:", you follow with an algorithm, and the answer is something in big O notation.  You gave us the time complexity in your question, so I'm a little confused.  What kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

L is constant so you can rewrite it as

O(n log(log(n)) + O(n)

as n is less than n log(log(n)) the result is

O(n log(log(n))

Comment: -1. You can't make a O(n)=O(L) assumption. If i have a connected network with N nodes and L links between them, N <= L <= N^2, so O(N) and O(L) are distinct things. The formula ssss@ posted cannot be simplified.

Comment: @iluxa I didn't say that n=L i just sad that n is a variable and L is a constant so O(L) is a constant. You're example is completely different from the question. Because L change as N change. In this case L is the length of the string which has nothing to do with the string number. In your example O(L) could be substituted by O(N^2), but that's a really different example!